# IOS10 Firebase Dynamic Link Show a Blank Page with Open Button. But Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

[blank image show if app not installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJnFi.png)

I tried to implement firebase dynamic link. It works perfectly if app installed in device but it shows this page if app not installed.It happens every time i try to go to app store. Does anyone have any solution? Please Let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

If you've created the link manually through firebase console. You can skip the app preview page by editing your link from the console.

```
-> Dynamic Links 
-> Edit Link 
-> under 'Campaign tracking, social tags and advanced options'
-> check 'Skip the app preview page'
```

[image: firebase dynamic link skip the app preview page]

Comment: Thanks for showing me the checkbox location... It's a clumsy interface.

Comment: how to turn on this option if i created the dynamic link programatically ?

Answer (score 5):

This is intentional as a way to help you get around the fact that some apps prefer to show all web content inside of their own in-app WebView and make it difficult for JavaScript redirects (like what Firebase Dynamic Links typically does) to take you to the App Store.

That said, I know it's not always a great experience, so the team is looking into adding an option to make this interstitial page optional for your links.

**EDIT:** There's now a way to skip the interstitial if you'd like. Add the argument `efr=1` to your link URL, and it will skip the page and attempt to redirect you directly to the appropriate location. If you're generating a link in the console, you can click the "Skip the app preview page" checkbox in the advanced options.

Comment: Hey @Todd it seems we have a different issue now -- if we set the "efr" flag [efr=1] it bypasses the interstitial page (appid-someletter.app.goo.gl) and loads appid.app.goo.gl but we get a Safari alert to "Open this page in 'App Store'?" rather than redirect to store -- is there a workaround here?

Comment: Hey @Todd any workaround if i want to open my website's webpage directly. instead of this blank page with open button.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal. If user clicks on the link it will lead to the correct download page on the app store.

Before iOS10, dynamic links were directly leading to the app store without this transition page. Changes in Safari security setup force them to add this page.