# Firebase Dynamic Links | Short links won't open directly on mobile

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm moving from goo.gl to FDL. I'm only using it to generate short links for campaigns. The problem is when short links are open on a mobile device, it shows a screen with the message "Save my place in the app. A link will be copied to continue to this page", and a button OPEN to continue.

How do I skip this screen and go directly to the long url.

When I open the same short link on a desktop browser, it doesn't show this screen and goes directly to the long url.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470255/ios10-firebase-dynamic-link-show-a-blank-page-with-open-button-but-why

Comment: I added efr=1 and nothing happened. Same result yet. So, it's not DUPLICATED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here:
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/url-shortener

> If you only want to create short links for web URLs, create a
>   placeholder iOS app in your Firebase project from the Project Overview
>   page of the Firebase console. (Specify any value for the bundle ID and
>   skip the subsequent steps).

Also, when creating the short url using [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest), don't add app information like **iosInfo** or **iosBundleId**. Send only this:

```
{
  "dynamicLinkInfo": {
    "dynamicLinkDomain": "yourdomain.page.link",
    "link": "https://the_link_you_want_to_short.com"
  }
}
```

It will return a short URL that will skip the screen I mentioned on my question above.

Answer (score 5):

You can skip that step (app preview page) by set enableForcedRedirect to true as shown in example code below. However, this is not recommended by firebase as they claim that the app preview page increases your click to install rate.

Here is the full list of API:
[Firebase Dynamic Links Short Links API Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener)

```
{
  "dynamicLinkInfo": {
    "domainUriPrefix": "https://example.page.link",
    "link": "https://example.come?referral_code=123",
    "androidInfo": {
      "androidPackageName": "com.example",
      "androidFallbackLink": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example"
    },
    "iosInfo": {
      "iosBundleId": "org.reactjs.native.example",
      "iosFallbackLink": "https://apps.apple.com/my/app/example/id1234567890",
    },
    "navigationInfo": {
      "enableForcedRedirect": true
    },
    "socialMetaTagInfo": {
      "socialTitle": "My Website Title",
      "socialDescription": "I am dummy description.",
      "socialImageLink": "https://example.com/imgs/example.png"
    }
  },
  "suffix": {
    "option": "SHORT"
  }
}
```

If you create the dynamic link on Firebase console, you can select "Skip the app preview page". If the link already created, just click on edit.

[image: firebase dynamic link skip the app preview page]